# Prevent an SSL cipher

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis, ssl

I checked a site that I'm deploying (IIS 8, Asp.net-C#, SSL), using [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)  as suggested on [Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.es/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html). It showed that "This server accepts the RC4 cipher, which is weak.".

How can I prevent that? The site is hosted on a web hosting environment so I don't have direct control over IIS, and I couldn't find anything in IIS manager for that. Is there something I can do on the site? Some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not be able to do this if you have a shared hosting environment, but you could contact your hosting company with the [following information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2868725).

> ## How to completely disable RC4
>
> Clients and servers that do not want to use RC4 regardless of the
>   other party’s supported ciphers can disable RC4 cipher suites
>   completely by setting the following registry keys. In this manner, any
>   server or client that is talking to a client or server that must use
>   RC4 can prevent a connection from occurring. Clients that deploy this
>   setting will be unable to connect to sites that require RC4, and
>   servers that deploy this setting will be unable to service clients
>   that must use RC4.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 128/128]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 40/128]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 56/128]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if they (-web host) can help. +1.